# SMD capacitor damaged - use of X2 class

Tags: ac, surface-mount, bypass-capacitor

I have a question about the need of the use of the X2 capacitor. I have a simple design which can be connected to AC line and I not use an X2 class capacitor but I m using an SMD capacitor from Murata (GA255DR7E2104MW01L) (size much more compact than THT X2 capacitor). However somedays, I discover that the SMD capacitor C1 is damaged (cc) which cause the damage of the two resistors (R1 and R2). For this circuit I use also a unidirectionnal TVS diode which is the P4SMA400A, to avoid overvoltage. So is there any need to use an X2 capacitor for my case? Otherwise what can be the real cause of the failure of this capacitor. I thank you for your help. 
[image]

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

Considering you are applying a low loss 2k source R to a 50k Load with a nominal input  of 339Vp to a 250V 0.1uF ceramic cap, it is no wonder that it failed.  The only choice here is an X2 rated film cap which attenuates 1kV To 3kV lightning transients as per your unstated CE requirements.

Start with worst case power & transient specs, then your choices become clear using your regional power standards.

Comment: I thank you for your answer. However, I haven't succeed to resimulate the failure of the capacitor. Every time,  I try to apply an overvoltage I break the TVS diode and not the capacitor. Is there any value of signal to stress also the capacitor(by changing the frequency of the signal maybe ??)

Comment: And X2 capacitor take much more place and I doesn't find an equivalent SMD capacitor class X2 with value equal to 100nF

Comment: Don’t use SMD since the Dk is far less than ceramic. you can also use much lower C values with a line filter type toroidal choke. Look up line Pi filter after you define safety standard and transient attenuation for Vimpulse.

Comment: I have found a capacitor rated 1kV also from murata (GRM55DR73A104KW01L) but I'm not sure if it will resist to overvoltage as it's a non safety capacitor

Comment: Keep looking as I suggested. Leaded film cap or Pi CLC line filter but do what I asked 1st. **define specs.**. Your homework.!

Comment: Thanks. I will look to PI CLC filter. However can you explain to me how it can happens the breaks of the capacitor as it's rated 250 VAC or for the second case 1KV(GRM55DR73A104KW01L). Thanks

Comment: who knows what line tolerances you have , enclosure temp rise and Arrhenius Law reduction on MTBF. caps have short finite lifespan at rated temps from which You can extrapolate based on specs for actual vs expected and temp rise.

Comment: @ Sunnyskyguy EE75 : I want to know is-there any fundamental rule to define the values of line capacitor ? 100nf or 10nf are generally the most value used for this AC line capacitor.

Comment: In addition, the PI filter must be put after the bridge rectifier in my circuit. Sorry, but I don't understand how the PI filter will resolve my issue with overvoltage which break my capacitor placed before the bridge rectifier. If I have well understand you suggestion, I have to add a PI filter after the bridge rectifier and I have to remove resistor (R1 and R2) and place an X2 capacitor. Is-it correct ? Thanks.

Comment: No the Line filter replaces the 1k R’s and 0.1uF with a LPF using chokes and smaller C. where are your specs?

Comment: Transient voltage 2kV. The nominal voltage is 240 VAC (+/- 10%)

Comment: There is no ressource on Line choke filter before Bridge diode. All support that I find is talking about choke filter after Bridge diode. I thank you to give me some example, more details (e.g simulation of the circuit with choke filter).Thanks.

Comment: All PC PSU’s (SMPS) use them before the bridge diodes.

Comment: Thanks for this indication. However for my case I have not much place on my pcb to place much more component especially that it's an old design So I want a very a lower cost redesign solution. Meanwhile can you explain much more your explanation about a source with 2 K and a load with 50K. What's wrong in this approach. I thank you for your precious explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on Surge and Burst requirements you have to use a cap which will absorve the high voltage, for conducted emission no much problem, you could use any type for testing, works well. But if you are in doubt about it, just see the safety standard, (like UL950 or IEC61950, or any other, the standard ask for safety type for certification, if you insist to use any, to get the approval, need to approval the capacitor alone for this function. So much more expensive. Sorry just follow the rules.

Answer (score 0):

As correctly noted, surge voltages are limited, so this is an unlikely failure mode.

It IS still over ratings, as others have noted.  In particular, look at the peak voltage drop of the TVS diode.  It is over 400V, so a capacitor rating of probably 630V or higher is called for.  The capacitor likely doesn't fail the instant you tip past 250V -- but how far beyond, or for how long, you have no guarantee of.

Given the size (2220 chip), I would suspect mechanical cracking.  Try a flex-termination type, or split it up into smaller chips.  IPC recommends maximum 1210 size; 1812 or larger may be acceptable under gentler conditions (or with flex terminations, or the lead frame types ($$$)).  Note that a non-X2 rated film capacitor isn't much larger anyway, and costs significantly less.

Note the resistors MUST be pulse/surge rated, since they will be taking the brunt of things instead of any filter capacitors (as X2 are usually intended for).  Check the peak voltage, power and energy ratings.

Side note: I'm impressed, that capacitor actually retains 60% of its rated value at rated voltage.  Type 2 dielectrics you have to watch out for, that their values under DC voltage bias don't utterly disappear.  This can be another good reason to choose film types.  (C0G and other type 1 dielectrics are as stable as film, so would also be an excellent choice, and offer higher energy density at these voltages -- but they're even more expensive, too.)